# Force HTTPS on .htaccess but only on production

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have been looking around for a snippet of code that will force `https://`. I've found this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The problem is when I want to work on local so a url like "localhost" or "example.dev" it tries to redirect to `https://localhost` (it doesn't work).

How do I solve this?

(so to sum it all up, I want the snippet above to work only when I use it on production, e.g "example.com")

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I want the snippet above to work only when I use it on production, e.g `example.com`)

You can restrict your rule to only target `example.com` using a rewrite condition:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: will this work with or without the `www` ?  So either will force the SSL?

Answer (score 2):

For Apache, put your rules within `<IfModule mod_ssl.c></IfModule>` block, and disable ssl module on your local server.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat advanced but you can try to put your servers in
a file called servers.txt

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap lb rnd:servers.txt
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://${lb:servers}/$1 [P,L]
serverlist.txt will contain a list of the servers:

## serverlist.txt file con
servers localhost.example.com|server1.example.com
```

The above answer is good enough with local and production 
differences in mod rewrite behavior. I would version the 
.htaccess in git or subversion (which ever you use) 
in that case.

This is mainly for load balancing but you can apply that in your mechanism.